# Table Joins SQL/PHP (CRUD)

Tags: php, mysql, crud, table-relationships

I have two tables like this:

```
[tblFacilityHrs] id uid title description
[tblFacilityHrsDateTimes] id owner_uid startEventDate endEventDate startTime endTime days recurrence finalDate
```

They are in a one-to-many relationship by way of UID:
[image]

[image]

I want to join the tables so that I only get the ID value from tblFacilityHrsDateTimes (so that when I edit the tables the first table tblFacilityHrs gets edited by UID and tblFacilityHrsDateTimes gets edited by ID).

How can I join the tables so they can be edited in this manner?

Something like this:

```
<?php 
include('../config.php'); 
if (isset($_GET['uid']) ) { 
$uid = (int) $_GET['uid'];
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];  
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) { $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); } 

//Query for tblFacilityHrs
$sql = "`title` =  '{$_POST['title']}' ,  `description` =  '{$_POST['description']}'   WHERE `uid` = '$uid' "; 
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

//Query for tblFacilityHrsDateTimes
$sql2 = "`startEventDate` =  '{$_POST['startEventDate']}' ,  `endEventDate` =  '{$_POST['endEventDate']}' ,  `startTime` =  '{$_POST['startTime']}',  `endTime` =  '{$_POST['endTime']}' ,  `days` =  '{$_POST['days']}' ,  `recurrence` =  '{$_POST['recurrence']} ,  `finalDate` =  '{$_POST['finalDate']}' WHERE `id` = '$id' "; 
mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error()); 

echo (mysql_affected_rows()) ? "Edited row.<br />" : "Nothing changed. <br />"; 
echo "<a href='list.php'>Back</a>"; 
} 
$row = mysql_fetch_array (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblFacilityHrs` WHERE `uid` = '$uid'"));
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblFacilityHrsDateTimes` WHERE `id` = '$id'"));
?>
```

In my head I imagine the tables joining like this (but it doesn't work):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid, title, description FROM tblFacilityHrs LEFT JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes ON tblFacilityHrs.uid = tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid ORDER BY tblFacilityHrs.description") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).  Also, you say the query at the end of your post "doesn't work" without explaining what it is that "doesn't work".  Do you get an error?  If so, what is it?  If not, how does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: I'm going prepare the statements in the future I'm not to that point yet. I'm doing one thing at a time so that I can debug. As for the join if I use that last code block it only displays information from tblFacilityHrs -- like this: http://i.imgur.com/XP5Yj.png

Comment: But your `SELECT` statement is only selecting the three columns explicitly named from `tblFacilityHrs`... why would you expect anything else in your resultset?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: How can I select only those three columns and then all of the table tblFacilityHrsDateTimes by uid?

Comment: `SELECT uid, title, description, tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.* FROM ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11026/discussion-between--and-eggyal)

Comment: Your existing code only passes the `id` in the querystring to `edit.php`; you want to make the hyperlink `<a href=edit.php?id={$row['id']}&uid={$row['uid']}>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

You need to select the columns from `tblFacilityHrsDateTimes` into your resultset:

```
SELECT      uid, title, description, tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.*
FROM        tblFacilityHrs
  LEFT JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes
         ON tblFacilityHrs.uid = tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid
ORDER BY    tblFacilityHrs.description
```